# How to enable the “Tags & Notes” tab inside my enterprise wiki

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, publishing-page, tags

I am working on a publishing site of type enterprise wiki , but currently the “Tags & Notes” icon is displayed.  As follow:-

[image]

And it mentioned that I might not have the permission, although I am the site administrator and part of the contributor group .

Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks